# How would I install this locally? Will gem install work?

Tags: ruby

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api

I've never manually installed something like this before, I have only used `gem install xxxx` in the past.

I am using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/).

**Update**

**OK, `gem install` does work, but how would I install it manually?**

Comment: Why do you want to install it manually? What do you mean by manually?

Comment: Very confuddling question. What does "install manullay" mean ? If you ran `gem install`, that was manual right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a gem so you could download it and decompress it, cd into its directory, then run rake. But why? gem install will be less work and will do as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
gem install path/to/gem/file.gem
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a gem, it's available from Rubygems, so

```
gem install shopify_api
```

See https://rubygems.org/gems/shopify_api